# Как правильно указать относительный путь

Tags: c++, visual-studio

У меня в проекте находится файл: *Folder/Headers/Mics/*

Отсюда я пытаюсь обратиться к файлу, который лежит в *Folder*:

```
D3DReadFileToBlob(L"..\\..\\File.cso",&pBlob);
```

Но он не может найти путь, если указать полный путь: *D:.....\File.cso*, тогда все нормально

Comment: Используйте полный путь.

Comment: @user7860670 А если мне нужно через относительный?

Comment: Делайте из относительного полный.

Comment: @user7860670 как можно его превратить в полный? используется windows :)

Comment: Для простоты склейте полный путь к папке, относительно который этот путь должен быть относителен, и сам путь. Заметьте, что типичная ошибка у новичков - полагать, что относительный путь - это путь относительно папки с проектом или папки, где лежит exe.

Comment: Скорее всего, вы неверно указати относительный путь. Он относителен не относительно каталога проекта, а относительно **текущего** каталога при выполнении программы.